# How to hide ItemInfo Interaction without using Modal/hideonmasktap properties in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-charts

I want to use ItemInfo interaction in my sencha touch charts but do not want to use modal/hideonmasktap properties concept. it should not grey out the whole background.
When i tap on chart then there should be ItemInfo interaction panel shown and if I will tap again anywhere on screen then it should be disappeared but without using that greyed out concept which comes with modal/hideonmasktap properties.

Please help.

Thanks!!